# Linux Command to Convert an Absolute Path to a Current Existing Relative Path

Tags: linux, path, relative-path

I already have the relative path: `/home/Folder1/Folder2` which its original absolute path is `/home/user1/Folder1/Folder2`. And I have several scripts that are using `/home/Folder1/Folder2`. Now, I need to delete user1 so I created user2 with the same structure of user1 so now I have a new path which is `/home/user2/Folder1/Folder2`. If I delete user1, my scripts will then fail because they are using the relative path `/home/Folder1/Folder2` which its original absolute path is `/home/user1/Folder1/Folder2`. So I want my new path `/home/user2/Folder1/Folder2` to point to `/home/Folder1/Folder2` so that my scripts won't fail and I don't want to go through the trouble of opening each script and change the relative path to my new created path. Any idea how I can do this?

Comment: What have you tried and how did it fail?

Answer (score 0):

I guess, you got confused between soft links and absolute/relative path.

I assume you have a soft link created from "/home/Folder1/Folder2" pointing to "/home/user1/Folder1/Folder2" and you want to delete user1 directory and create user2 directory with same structure. If my assumption is right, recreate the softlink "/home/Folder1/Folder2" to point to "/home/user2/Folder1/Folder2". Your existing scripts will work seamlessly.